# CSS Background Image left of Div in Flex Container

Tags: html, css

here is my code

```
  .usp-bar {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            background-color: #005932;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 700;
            padding: 10px 0;
            margin-top: 0;
            justify-content: center;
            height: auto;
        }
    
    .usp-text {
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    .icon {
        background-image: url(/media/icon.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
```

And here the HTML

```
<div class="usp-bar">
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="usp-text">USP 1</div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="usp-text">USP 2</div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="usp-text">USP 3</div>
</div>
```

I want to have the icon left of my text. The bar is full width and should be full responsive. The 3 text items are centered. Thats all ok, but now I want an icon left of every of the 3 text boxes but the icon is like a background image and the text overlays this in my current setting.

Can you help me pls?

Comment: Why do you want to put an icon in background, but not directly in HTML?

Comment: do you want to give background image to `usp-text` class and position it to right?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> -->
    <style>
      .usp-bar {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background-color: #005932;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        height: auto;
      }
      .icon {
        background-image: url('https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/50/000000/networking-manager.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
      }
      .box {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 1rem;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="usp-bar">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="usp-text">USP 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="usp-text">USP 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="usp-text">USP 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

check this code if thats you are looking

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-aqmerr working example